# How to debug if image is not uploading to the server

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to upload image to the server and save the file name in MySql. I am uploading from image from Android Application , i am sending all the required params from android app but still something is wrong in copy image in server. It is echoing "Upload Failed".

```
<?php

$uploaddir = 'DocumentClient/';
$cid=$_POST['cid'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$filetype = $_POST['filetype'];

include('../Config.php');

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","$username","$password","$db");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
else
{
        $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]=$cid.$type.".jpg";

        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

        if (copy($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
        {
        $filename="DocumentClient/".$_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"];  
        if($type == "Address"){
            $sql = "Update `Clients` SET `DocAddress`='$filename' Where CID='$cid'";
        }else if($type == "ID"){
            $sql = "Update `Clients` SET `DocIdProof`='$filename' Where CID='$cid'";
        }else if($type == "GramPanchayat"){
            $sql = "Update `Clients` SET `DocGrampanchyat`='$filename' Where CID='$cid'";
        }

            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
            {

            } 
            else 
            {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;    
            }
        $conn->close();
    }
    else 
    {
    echo "Upload failed";
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: It would help if you defined *something is wrong*, is the database updated, is the image there but corrupt, does anything happen in the PHP?

Comment: I think problem in my php script because its not copying file in folder so thats why it is not storing anything in db because of if condition. @NigelRen

Comment: What errors are you getting?  We can not help you if you do not tell us more information about your problem.  What is not working correctly?  Also your script is vulnerable to sql injection.  Please read about parameterized queries.

Comment: It is echoing Upload Failed. That means it is not Copying image in folder. @Joseph_J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start here.  I would change the `copy()` function to the `move_uploaded_file()` function.

Secondly, You need to check to make sure the path for the download destination exist.  If it does not then we need to create it.

We also need to make sure the folder/file has permissions to be able to write.  If it does not then change the folder/files permission.

Then when done, change your folder/files permissions back to what they were originally.

Like so:

```
$uploaddir = 'DocumentClient/';
$cid=$_POST['cid'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$filetype = $_POST['filetype'];

include('../Config.php');

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","$username","$password","$db");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
else
{
        $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]=$cid.$type.".jpg";

        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

        //Check to see if the folder exist.
        if(!file_exists($uploaddir)) {

        mkdir($uploaddir, 0777, true); //If it does not exist then create it and set permissions to be able to write.

        }

        //The folder does exist at this point. Check to see if it's writable.
        if(!is_writable($uploaddir)){

          chmod($uploaddir, 0777); //The folder is not writeable. Set the folder to be able to write.

        }

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
        {
        $filename="DocumentClient/".$_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"];  
        if($type == "Address"){
            $sql = "Update `Clients` SET `DocAddress`='$filename' Where CID='$cid'";
        }else if($type == "ID"){
            $sql = "Update `Clients` SET `DocIdProof`='$filename' Where CID='$cid'";
        }else if($type == "GramPanchayat"){
            $sql = "Update `Clients` SET `DocGrampanchyat`='$filename' Where CID='$cid'";
        }

            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
            {

            } 
            else 
            {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;    
            }
        $conn->close();

        //Reset the permissions back to what you need them to be.
        //You probably want 0755
        chmod($uploaddir, 0755);
        chmod($uploadfile, 0644); //Sets your new file to read only.

        //Add this code below to test.
        if(file_exists($uploadfile)) {

        echo 'Your file exist.';

        }else{

          echo 'You file does not exist.';

          }

    }
    else 
    {
    echo "Upload failed";
    }

}
```

Some resources for you to read.

[move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

[is_writeable()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php)

[chmod()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)

You will also want to read up on file permissions an how to properly set them. Not doing this correctly can leave you open to unwanted security issues.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is entering data in to Mysql but not storing any file in folder yet.

Comment: Any errors anywhere? And are you sure you have refreshed your screen to see if the files have shown up in your directory.

Comment: No, response is ""

Comment: Yes now it is updating db

Comment: I added some code in my answer to test to see if the file is on your server.  Please add code and run and let me know what it says.  Thanks.

Comment: Now it responded with "Your file exist" but not storing file.

Comment: If it said that the file is on your server.  Check around your file system..  It's somewhere.  You may need to put the full path in for the `DocumentClient/`

Comment: Ohh yeah i got it but it is out of public_html. Can't i store inside public_html?

Comment: Yeah, you just need to better define your path.  Use your full project path for the `$uploaddir`.  Once you get you path figured out it will work just fine.

Comment: Thnxx. Everything is perfect now.

Comment: Cool!!  Read up on how to define your paths.  There are a few ways to do it.  Understanding that now will help out a lot later.  Good luck on the rest of your project!  ~Cheers!